# Flash AS2: Opening other SWFs using Relative Paths on a networked drive

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, relative-path

### Issue

We cannot seem to get an original .SWF to load its partner .SWF files.  While the `<object>` tag will load its file properly, the .SWF cannot load other .SWFs into it.  The ActionScript is autogenerated via AS2 "Behaviors", and basically calls either `loadMovieNum(file, this)` or `this.LoadMovie(file)`, depending on how it was loaded previously.  Each group of .SWFs that reference one another will exist on a drive-mapped network share.

### Facts

- A Client is using the "Behaviors" feature of ActionScript 2.0
- Said behavior is to load other .SWF files in the same path depending on an onRelease() event
- Neither the Client, nor ourselves, are fluent with Flash & ActionScript.
- The .SWF will be hosted in HTML inside of a custom application
- The software programmatically loads HTML from a stream, not a file.
- Said HTML uses the standard `<object>` tag to host the Flash .SWF
- The primary .SWF is located underneath a mapped networked drive (example: "K:\") in a series of subfolders.
- The group of .SWFs will reside in the same folder
- Our controlled environment is WinXP+SP3 and Flash 9, with extremely-limited ability to update.
- They are **strongly** against using absolute paths, as it will affect reuse of certain .SWF groups.

Using Process Monitor and dabling with the `"base" <param>`, we have seen the following:

1. Without the param, it tries to find the .SWF as a Registry value underneath AboutURLs.  This is likely a side effect of our app initially pointing to "about:blank" before dynamically loading the HTML.
2. With the full path ("K:\test\sub\") as base, it tries to find the SWF on the root of the "C:\"
3. Testing with a real HTML file (not yet able to test with the App), providing a full path without the drive letter ("\test\sub\") will navigate to this path from the same drive as the HTML.  Given our limitation (the "about:blank" thing), this probably will either be the "C:\" **OR** the Registry.

### Question

Is this possible by using any HTML/JavaScript on our end, or will we have to have some ActionScript that will determine the current SWF's path, use that to dynamically obtain the location of the other SWFs (also in the same path), then try to teach this Client how to implement the script?  Again, they (and we) know little about Flash; they used "Behaviors" to try and get this to work.

Comment: We currently provided a possible alternative to the client which does require ActionScript changes.  Using the _URL property, we can get the full path to the current SWF.  From there, we get the path via finding the last directory separator (unless there's a better function for it).  Then, with that path, we just append the SWF filename we wish to open.  It appears to work, and hopefully said Client is okay with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: Consider using a webserver to host your flash, if you have any chances of doing that with your app. Loading from a file over a LAN is going to cause a lot of problems that is difficult to resolve and you may have dug yourself in to deep here.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have that luxury.  The environments are something that have existed for many years, with a mix of legacy and newer code working between them.  Web servers are not currently supported here.  Normally, we don't deal with Flash, or if we do, it is a single self-contained file. External media like audio, video, and images generally work okay (aside from the occasional Codec issue we have to resolve), but Flash (at least AS2) appears to have its own restrictions.

Comment: As an aside, it also appears that another development project for a different (set of) client(s) decided to use SilverLight for video rendering, for its advanced features and our team's knowledge of .NET.  As a note, it appears that SilverLight apparently MUST run from a webserver when interfacing with HTML/Browser control.  So they are using a webserver to host the content in this case.  In the future, our use of Flash may be able to piggyback on this.